# the use of regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm new in regular expression, but I want to match a pattern in about 2 million strings.
There three forms of the origin strings shown as follows:

```
EC-2A-07<EC-1D-10>
EC-2-07
T1-ZJF-4
```

I want to get three parts of substrings besides `-`, which is to say I　want to get `EC`, `2A`, `07`respectively. Especially, for the first string, I just want to divide the part before `<`.

I have tried `.+[\d]\W`, but cannot recognize `EC-2-07`, then I use `.split('-')` to split the string, and then use index in the returned list to get what I want. But it is low efficient.

Can you figure out a high efficient regular expression to meet my requirements?? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try [`([A-Z0-9]{2})-([A-Z0-9]{1,3})-([A-Z0-9]{1,2})`](https://regex101.com/r/8iMy6k/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You really reply faster than the question takes to be asked! i never have time on regex questions lol

Comment: @antoni: I am just suggesting something that seems to work, but there is no guarantee it will work for OP as the actual requirements are missing. It takes much more time to provide a valid, good answer. And a clear question, of course.

Comment: Thanks~But it seems get the strings inside `<>`, which is what I want to neglect.

Comment: What is eligible as a value , can you please decide ? In EC-2A-07<EC-1D-10> why "07<EC-1D-1D-10>" can not be regarded as a value ? If you say because < is there ... that make it clear, only < will make that the rest is not needed, or if there is anything else, also make it clear... as you are talking about 2 millions of string !

Comment: It is my fault that I didn't make it clear. The whole 2 million strings have and only have the three forms as shown above. In the first situation, I just need the part before `<`, and divide it into 3 parts.

Comment: @QM.py: If you use that pattern with `re.match`, it will only match the pattern at the start of the string. See https://regex101.com/r/8iMy6k/2

Comment: See https://ideone.com/dlslcT

Comment: I see your comments now, it works~~I'll try to figure it out! Thanks a lot. Re is really beyond my scope.

Comment: Please see my answer below, and please consider accepting if it works for you and upvoting if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
^([A-Z0-9]{2})-([A-Z0-9]{1,3})-([A-Z0-9]{1,2})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8iMy6k/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Z0-9]{2})` - Group 1 capturing 2 uppercase ASCII letters or digits
  -`-` - a hyphen
- `([A-Z0-9]{1,3})` - Group 2 capturing 1 to 3 uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([A-Z0-9]{1,2})` - Group 3 capturing 1 to 2 uppercase ASCII letters or digits.

You may adjust the values in the `{min,max}` quantifiers as required.

Sample [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dlslcT):

```
import re
regex = r"^([A-Z0-9]{2})-([A-Z0-9]{1,3})-([A-Z0-9]{1,2})"
test_str = "EC-2A-07<EC-1D-10>\nEC-2-07\nT1-ZJF-4"
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
#or with lines
lines = test_str.split('\n')
rx = re.compile("([A-Z0-9]{2})-([A-Z0-9]{1,3})-([A-Z0-9]{1,2})")
for line in lines:
    m = rx.match(line)
    if m:
        print('{0} :: {1} :: {2}'.format(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)(?=\W).*$
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/5D9BeE/1)

[Python Demo](https://repl.it/EAM9)